# HttpUtility.ParseQueryString() always encodes special characters to unicode

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, query-string

When using HttpUtility from System.Web, I find that everytime I call the method .ParseQueryString I am having special characters encode to their unicode equivalent representations. I have tried with many different encoding types, and all seem to produce the same result. An example of my code is here:

```
string text = "ich möchte diese Bild für andere freigeben"
var urlBuilder = new UriBuilder(url);
var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(urlBuilder.Query, Encoding.UTF8);
query["text"] = text;    
urlBuilder.Query = query.ToString();
string finalUrl = urlBuilder.ToString();
```

And the string in `finalUrl` that I would recieve from this would be:

> text=ich+m%u00f6chte+diese+Bild+f%u00fcr+andere+freigeben

I have tried using `Encoding.UTF8`,`Encoding.ASCII` and `Encoding.Default` and they all produce the same result. What can I do to reach my desired format of UrlEncoding:

> text=ich%20m%C3%B6chte%20diese%20Bild%20f%C3%BCr%20andere%20freigeben

As always, Thanks in advance for the help/advice!

Comment: what would you recommend?

Comment: Just as a side note, you may want to show them as non-encoded, but the URL specification clearly indicates these should be encoded. https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt (around the page 2 marker)

Comment: Its not that i dont want to encode them, its that i want it to show up as standard url encoding vs unicode encoding.

Answer (score 28):

The problem is in:

```
urlBuilder.Query = query.ToString();
```

`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` returns a `NameValueCollection` but is actually an internal class called `HttpValueCollection`. This class has an override of the `ToString()` method. It generates an encoded query string but for its URL encoding it uses `HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode` (tinyurl.com/HttpValue). This results in the %uXXXX values.

If you need a different type of URL encoding you might want to avoid `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` or decode the result of `ToString()` and encode it afterwards:

```
urlBuilder.Query = Uri.EscapeDataString(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(query.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 12):

This question is rather old, but I just came across it while researching this problem and noticed that it's missing a valid answer.

The fix is fairly simple, in the `web.config` simply add the following setting (tested and works in .NET 4.5):

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="aspnet:DontUsePercentUUrlEncoding" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Setting this value to true controls how .NET will encode certain characters in the URL. Specifically characters like ä, ë, ö etc. I think this might be because there are several ways these characters can be encoded. The way this generally done is with the prefix `%C3` which denotes that the following character has an umlaut (I'm fairly sure that's how it works).

The way `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` does it by default is different. It encodes the character to the actual percentage encoded unicode character `%u00f6`. This can cause some issues because it's not the default even within .NET itself, `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` for instance will encode it to `%C3%B6`. Changing the above setting will make sure that both methods return similar results.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with ParseQueryString, but it appears from the documentation to convert a properly formatted query into name value pairs.  From your post it appears you are trying to do the opposite: convert data pairs to a properly formatted query.  Instead you may try using HttpUtility.UrlEncode

```
string text = "ich möchte diese Bild für andere freigeben"
var urlBuilder = new UriBuilder(url);
String query = "text=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(text);  
urlBuilder.Query = query;
string finalUrl = urlBuilder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use: System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.Url.Query, UTF8Encoding.Default)

For Example: www.mydomain.com/page?name=Jia+Almi%F1a&PAYID=123456&TOWN=LONDON

Actual Name: Jia Almiña

Request.Querystring["name"]: Jia Almi�a (which isn't correct)

First get the Raw url which will be
Request.Url.Query: ?name=Jia+Almi%F1a&PAID=123456&TOWN=LONDON

System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.Url.Query, UTF8Encoding.Default).Get("name") will be Jia Almiña